# What was reset in the canon between Cyberpunk 2020 and Cyberpunk Red?

Tags: lore, edition-comparison, cyberpunk-2020, cyberpunk-red

Cyberpunk Red starts with a little text from the author of original Cyberpunk, and it contains in a nutshell, why Cyberpunk Red is not just a continuation of Cyberpunk 2020 and that there are a lot of changes. In fact, Mike Pondsmith promises that quite some things from Cyberpunk 2020 have been **reset** (or in other words: retconned) to make the backdrop of Cyberpunk Red, set in the 2040s, and placed *neatly* in the gap between the old CP2020 and the console title in 2077.

> In Cyberpunk, my solution has always been to treat the entire world like a giant comic book, divided up into roughly
> ten-year story arcs. The Cyberpunk world goes to hell beginning in 1993, starting with the invention of modern cyberware
> and the attack on the World Trade Center in New York by Colombian narco-terrorists. We start the main Cyberpunk
> story (what I call the Never Fade Away Arc) ten years later in 2013 with the culmination being Johnny Silverhand's invasion
> of the Arasaka Tower in an attempt to rescue his girlfriend, Alt Cunningham. Ten more years pass and then begins the
> Cyberpunk 2020 Arc (which I call the Fall of the Towers Arc… starting to see a pattern here, what with me destroying
> big buildings all the time?) by the end of which the Cyberpunk world is totally disrupted in 2023.
>
> Working in story arcs is useful. It allows you to keep the main world operational while creating new storylines and
> introducing new characters. You get to build on what is already there and familiar. But by the end of the 2020 Arc, I had
> two big problems. First, it wasn't going to be enough simply to start a new storyline. I had to deal with the fact that much
> of the existing world had been mined out and needed a reset.
>
> [...]
>
> Cyberpunk RED doesn't wreck the world. But it resets many of the elements of that world without having to make it
> unrecognizable. [...]

So... there's changes. Lots of them to be expected. The [*system comparison* was done alredy](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/154235/what-are-the-difference-between-cyberpunk-2020-and-cyberpunk-red) and came up to "more streamlined, feels very similar", but now it is going into the actual feel of the world: **Which elements of the CP2020 timeline got reset, retconned, declared non-happenings or spooled back or rewritten to Cyberpunk Red?**

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### [Nothing of Note](https://www.reddit.com/r/cyberpunkgame/comments/bjjeuk/yes_its_all_the_same_timeline_maxmike_pondsmith/)

The losses were all Cyberpunk v3.0 and CyberGeneration material. The first was declared non-canon a few years after it went on sale and the second is now a spin-off universe, if one of the 2020 problems spread out of control.

According to Mike Pondsmith (reddit, 2018, link in the title):

> Ahem. There's still an incorrect interview floating around the interwebs that states that Cyberpunk 2077 and Cyberpunk 2020 are separate timelines. To clear this up, I am posting RIGHT HERE AND NOW that the timeline is unified, with the path moving from Cyberpunk 2013 thru Cyberpunk 2020, then through Cyberpunk RED and up to Cyberpunk 2077.
>
> Lord knows, we spent enough time hashing the details out over the past six months. Expect more on this later. Back to your cyberlives, everyone.

In that same source:

> Generation actually happened in 2020, but not as extensively. The Carbon Plague was ended in a year. On the other hand, V3 is no longer canon.

Other lore differences are all a result of different perspectives on the same events.